# facebook share link url and prepopulating: not working on mobile

Tags: facebook, mobile

I'm attempting to share a link via email that opens up for the user to share stuff on their facebook page with prepopulated info. It works on laptops/desktops. But it does not work on mobile. Is there a way to format the url to open correctly in the mobile browser as well? Or even better yet, to open the share in the app?

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p%5Burl%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.espn.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobile sharer uses `u` as the parameter name:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.espn.com
```

You can use this link for both mobile and desktop since you need to use it in an email (sans detection scripts).